# Ant: Parallel build with external compiler

Tags: ant, build, parallel-processing, dependencies

I need some help on ant. How can I make ant behave similarly to `make -j <n>`? 
Note that I am not building java, but invoking an external compiler for a proprietary language.

While there is the task `<parallel>` (and an analogous attribute for `<for>`), they do not seem to support dependencies, or rather I haven't found a way to apply dependencies on these.

However, I do have the dependencies available in a properties file, formatted like this:

```
fileA=fileB fileC 
fileB=fileC
```

fileA/B/C are the basenames of my target files.

Currently there are some 850 files to build. Using a `<for>` I walk over this list (properly sorted by ironing out the dependencies) to invoke the compiler.
I was already advised to use `<sequential>`, however this would mean to translate the dependencies into blocks of `<sequential>` which is kind of bad.

Any ideas on how to make the `<for ... parallel="yes">` loop respect dependencies, or any other idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything in native Ant that can do this, but this example is an absolutely ideal use case for the "dataflow concurrency" model supported by Groovy's [GPars](http://www.gpars.org/0.12/guide/guide/7.%20Dataflow%20Concurrency.html), so you can do something with a script task:

```
<project name="gpars-test">
  <path id="groovy.path">
    <pathelement location="groovy-all-1.8.8.jar" />
    <pathelement location="gpars-0.12.jar" />
  </path>

  <!-- Target to build one file - expects a property "filetobuild"
       containing the name of the file to build -->
  <target name="buildOneFile">
    <echo>Imagine I just built ${filetobuild}...</echo>
  </target>

  <target name="main">
    <script language="groovy" classpathref="groovy.path"><![CDATA[
      import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.task
      import groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflows

      // load dependencies
      def deps = new Properties()
      new File(basedir, 'dependencies.properties').withInputStream {
        deps.load(it)
      }

      def df = new Dataflows()
      // spawn one "task" per file to be compiled
      deps.each { file, dependencies ->
        task {
          if(dependencies) {
            // wait for dependencies - reading df.something will suspend
            // this task until another task has written the same variable
            dependencies.split(/ /).each { dep ->
              def dummy = df."${dep}"
            }
          }

          // now we know all our dependencies are done, call out to build
          // this one.    
          def compiler = project.createTask('antcall')
          compiler.target = "buildOneFile"
          def prop = compiler.createParam()
          prop.name = "filetobuild"
          prop.value = file
          try {
              compiler.perform()
          } catch(Exception e) {
              // do something
          } finally {
              // we're done - this will release any other tasks that are blocked
              // depending on us
              df."${file}" = "done"
          }
        }
      }

      // now wait for all tasks to complete
      deps.each { file, dependencies ->
        def dummy = df."${file}"
      }
      println "finished"
    ]]></script>
  </target>
</project>
```

Note that this does assume that *all* the files you want to build are listed in the dependencies file, including those with no dependencies, i.e.

```
fileA=fileB fileC 
fileB=fileC
fileC=
```

If the no-deps file names aren't listed in the properties then you'll have to do some more fiddling to put them in there - immediately before the `def df = new Dataflows()` you'd need to add something along the lines of

```
deps.values().collect().each { depString ->
  depString.split(/ /).each {
    // if we find a fileX that something depends on but which does not
    // itself appear in the deps map, assume it has no dependencies
    if(!deps.containsKey(it)) {
      deps.setProperty(it, "")
    }
  }
}
```